# CSS - correct text vertical center align

Tags: css, text, vertical-alignment

I need to vertically align a text in center inside a div. I have found many of way, but none of them respects exact content of the text - I am talking about small graphical parts below text line - letter e.g. "ygq" etc., which is missing when e.g. capital letters are used "YGQ", but it's still counted when text is displayed. I tried:

```
.button {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

<div class="button">My text</div> 
<div class="button">MY TEXT</div>
```

and the other way

```
.button {
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

<div class="button"><p>My text</p></div> 
<div class="button"><p>MY TEXT</p></div>
```

I use padding attribute, when I am sure, no graphics below the line will be presented. Is there a way, how to align text generally based on its exact content?

Question [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css) doesn't answer this as the solution is based on "line-height" which still takes count graphics below line as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Mentioned "duplicate" question doesn't solve the issue - line-height includes space for graphics below the line as I mention in my question.

Answer (score 0):

To make your elements vertical center, you can use `display:flex` with the parent container `.button` and apply `margin:auto` to child element.

```css
 

.button{
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: aliceblue;
 }
.button p {
   margin: auto;
}
```

```html
    <div class="button">
        <p>My text</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```css
.button{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
        <p>My text</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use position and transform to align an item vertically inside an other

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
}

.button p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);

    /* For horizontal align */
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="button">
        <p>My text</p>
    </div>
```